# grpc push notifcation example in java

Tags: push-notification, grpc, grpc-java

I would like to know if there is a good tutorial to explain a push notification system using gRPC in Java. I found an example using go but I was wondering why there are not so many examples in this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is referred to as "Server-side Streaming" and you can read about it in the official [Getting Started docs for Java](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java.html#server-side-streaming-rpc).

Essentially you should define your proto file like so:

```
service PushNotifier {
  // A server-to-client streaming RPC.
  rpc Listen(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream PushNotification) {}

message PushNotification {
  string payload = 1
}
```

You can find examples [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples). Specifically, have a look into `routeguide` example, which shows 4 different types of gRPC communication.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes that is the solution. I also have another question. When we have multiple clients (i.e. multiple observers), we need to store observer objects (in the server side) in a data structrue like hashmap to call onNext function for its corresponding client correct? Is there any better solution?

Comment: Yes, that's correct and make sure to update the map and remove the StreamObserver once the client disconnects from the server. There might be a better option which I can't think of right now, but what you need to take into consideration is that the StreamObserver is valid as long as the client is connected to your server. On Android for example, you will need a foreground service running (with notification) to keep the connection alive when the user navigates away from the app. Most users won't like this. A better option would be  to utilize FCM whenever you want to "wake up" the app.